# How to fix NoReverseMatch at/blog/ Django 1.8 Url

Tags: python, django

I cant figure it out how my code doesnt work, trying to display post_detail.html, NoReverseMatch at /blog/
Reverse for 'post_detail' with arguments '(2,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog/$post/(?P\d+)/$']

Here my code:
**blog.views.py**

```
def post_list(request):
    posts =Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts':posts})

def post_detail(request, post_pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

**blog.urls.py**

```
app_name='blog'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<post_pk>\d+)/$',    views.post_detail,  name='post_detail'),
]
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^blog/$', include(blog_urls, namespace='blog')),
]
```

**post_list.html**

{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

```
{% for post in posts %}
    < -- here is the error
    <h1><a href="{% url 'blog:post_detail' post.pk %}">{{post.title}}</a></h1>
    <p>published by: {{ post.published_date }}</p>
    <p>{{post.author}}</p>
    <p>{{post.text|linebreaksbr}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

{% endblock%}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the regex end-of-string match character `$` from the url in `include`:

```
url(r'^blog/', include(blog_urls, namespace='blog')),
#           ^
```

This happens to be an anticipated error that the Django documentaion mentions it:

> Note that the regular expressions in this example don’t have a `$`
>   (end-of-string match character) but do include a trailing slash.
>   Whenever Django encounters `include()` (`django.conf.urls.include()`),
>   it chops off whatever part of the URL matched up to that point and
>   sends the remaining string to the included *URLconf* for further
>   processing.

Comment: Thanks for help and info sir, ive been strugling around 3 hours,